# How to write this chain without losing the promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, reduce, chain

I have this (simplified here) code when the "reading" function calls itself many times (it is actually reading a file by chunks). The problem is that by doing so (this is what I think), the chain is lost and the "then" of the upload() function is never reached.

In other words, the 'hola' text is never displayed in the console. What is the proper way to write this?

Thanks,

https://jsfiddle.net/yewdmh2o/1/

```
reading = function() {
    start++;
    upload();
};

var start = 0;
var end = 5;
var myArray = [3,5,7];
myArray.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return upload()
    .then(function(){
        console.log('hola');
    })
})

function upload() {
    if (start < end) {
        console.log('doing')
        reading();
    } else {
        console.log('finished')
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Solved with the help of @Bergi, by always returning a promise it can keep the chaining process and give the desired outcome, like this:

```
reading = function() {
    start++;
    return upload();
};

var start = 0;
var end = 5;
var myArray = [3,5,7];
myArray.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return upload()
    .then(function(){
        console.log('hola');
    })
})

function upload() {
    if (start < end) {
        console.log('doing')
        return reading();
    } else {
        console.log('finished')
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `upload` function isn't a promise... can you please provide a better example?

Comment: That's the question, should I include in the upload the defer lines? Since this is what I did but I'm reading this is not a good idea (http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/). Bottom-line message, I don't understand well promises, could you expand on your sentence?

Comment: @Gerard: Where is the asynchronous part in `upload`? Currently it's just a recursive function that counts from 0 to 5, nothing what a `while` loop couldn't do either.

Comment: @rpadovani that said, I return a Promise.resolve() (I wrote here a 1 by mistake). In my understanding this converted the upload() method in a promise (??)

Comment: @Gerard: You need to *always* return a promise, not only in the case where `end` is already reached

Comment: @Bergi, here it is not, in real code it is a FileReader that reads a file in chunks, so it is called several times until the full file is read, and then it should "resolve" and go back to the "then"

Comment: @Bergi, but how to implement this? I mean, if "end" is not reached, I want to call reading() that will call again upload() that eventually will reach "end" that then will return a promise. If I return a promise no matter what, I guess the code loses its logic?

Comment: @Gerard: Then `reading` will need to return a promise as well, so that you basically got mutual recursion.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post your real code.

Comment: I've updated the question. As you say, by returning a Promise in upload or by chaining it to the other functions solves the error, but it gives twice the log. Real code is just impossible, I could do another simplification but if I copy-paste it it won't help. However, if I solve this code I think I'll solve my code as well.

Comment: @Bergi, silly me, it is giving twice the answer because of the Array.reduce. But the code should work now. I am doubting between deleting the question or re-editing it and close it if you provide an answer.